# Python get first k elements from the list, which are present in another list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a `list1`:

```
        [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and another `list2`:

```
        [4, 2, 10, 20, 3, 1]
```

I want to take 1st 3 elements of `list2`, which are present in `list1`:

`Output-list`

```
        [4, 2, 3]
```

How to do this?

Comment: For each element in list 2, if that element is in list 1, add it to your output list. If the length of your output list is the desired length, break.

Comment: Thank you. Is that the most efficient way - I am also looking for efficiency as my lists are really big How about taking intersection of 2 lists and then taking the first 3 elements? Which of the approaches would be faster?

Comment: If order matters, then no, there's no way around iterating over list 2 at the very minimum the number of elements as you require in your desired output. If order doesn't matter, then sure, use set intersections.

Comment: Will there be duplicates in the lists?

Comment: no, there are no duplicates in either lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create `list comprehension` with a condition to check list2 in list1

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [4, 2, 10, 20, 3, 1]

output_list = [i for i in list2 if i in list1][0:3]
print(output_list)
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to break list comprehension as soon as 3 elements are obtained instead of forming the full list and then taking the 1st 3 elements?

Comment: Not Sure a `list comprehension` after nth iteration based on a conditional be broken. But instead of list comprehension we can create a `Generator`. Since Generator can calculate a value stops there and calculate next from where it left off when called again.Code can be like this:   ``` list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [4, 2, 10, 20, 3, 1]
output_Gen = (i for i in (list2) if i in list1) 
output_list = [next(output_Gen),next(output_Gen),next(output_Gen)]
print(output_list) ```

Answer (score 1):

If order of elements doesn't matter you can use set intersection. If it does, you need to iterate over list2:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [4, 2, 10, 20, 3, 1]

# If order of elements doesn't matter
common = set(list1).intersection(list2)
print(common)

# If order does matter
result = []
for element in list2:
    if element in list1:
        result.append(element)

    if len(result) >= 3:
        break

print(result)
```